# need a way to start an app from an icon

Tags: shortcuts

I have finally managed to get iReports working under Ubuntu 18.04. To start it I need to go to a command window, cd to /opt/iReports5.6.0/bin, and then type ./ireports. Why, I have no idea? If I type ireportes.exe in the bin directory it doesn't start. Regardless it took countless hours to get the correct version of java (1.7) to run instead of 1.8, which was a sticking issue. In Windows I would just create a shortcut to a batch file that would change the directory to /opt/iReports5.6.0/bin/ and then execute ./ireports. And I would then drop the shortcut onto the desktop.

Is there anything analagous in Ubuntu 18 world?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: "If I type ireportes.exe in the bin directory it doesn't start."   NOTE: Linux systems do not recognize ".exe" file extensions as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create desktop icon for your app. Follow these steps:

Open your terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt  install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel

gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Enter type, name, path to the application binary executable and optional comment. New desktop shortcut has now been created.

Double-click on the the new shortcut and select `Trust and Launch`. Set icon by right-click on the new desktop shortcut, selecting **Properties**. Next, click on the shortcut icon and choose path desired icon.

Comment: Thanks. I did the above but the program is not starting. For the executable I entered ireport.exe. As I said in the question, I can only start it by going to the bin directory and typing ./ireport. From my training, the .exe is the executable.